# How to keep 1.5 years worth of commit data without conflicts from merging?

Tags: git, github

I have a basic git flow inspired Git branching model, using a master branch and feature branches. I have one particular branch that was long-running and heavily trafficked, used for primary development for about 1.5 years, that I ended up throwing away. I don't want to lose all the history and statistics that I had on that branch, but I assume I can't merge it in since it's essentially two completely separate, large, code bases. Is there a way to merge the branch in and keep the history of the work I did during that period while still not leaving that dead branch on the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a clone of the repo, where you keep all the branches, including the long-running feature branch. In all the other repos just delete that branch and run the garbage collector `git gc` to clean up the branch's objects too.

If you decide later that you still want to use that branch, you can add the full-repo as a remote in the other repos and fetch it in.